# Not able to show i18n messages in spring webflow

Tags: spring, jsp, internationalization, spring-webflow

I am delevoping a web app with Spring MVC 3 and Spring Webflow 2.3.2.

I want to be able to add i18n messages on flow pages. It work ok on non-flow pages. I can switch language and it work ok.

But when user enter in web flow, only default messages are showed.
I am using `<spring:message />` tag.

I have googled that with no success.

This is my app-servlet.xml config:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/i18n/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60"/>
</bean>
```

And this is my webflow.xml config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven   />

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="-1" />
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
</bean>

<!-- Dispatches requests mapped to flows to FlowHandler implementations -->
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<!-- Executes flows: the entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener" />
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry"
    base-path="/WEB-INF/jsp" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" >
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>

<!-- Plugs in a custom creator for Web Flow views -->
<webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator" 
    conversion-service="conversionService"
    development="true" validator="validator" />

<bean id="conversionService" class="com.zxxztech.zecure.services.webflow.ApplicationConversionService">
    <constructor-arg ref="applicationConversionService" />
</bean>

<bean id="applicationConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />


<!-- Configures Web Flow to use Tiles to create views for rendering; Tiles allows for applying consistent layouts to your views -->
<bean id="mvcViewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
    <property name="viewResolvers" ref="tilesViewResolver"/> 
    <property name="useSpringBeanBinding" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Installs a listener to apply Spring Security authorities -->
<bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener" class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener" />

<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext " />
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>

<!-- Configures the Tiles layout system -->
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Resolves logical view names returned by Controllers to Tiles; a view 
    name to resolve is treated as the name of a tiles definition -->


<!-- Bootstraps JSR-303 validation and exposes it through Spring's Validator 
    interface -->
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

And this is a fragment of my jsp pages:

```
<div class="ym-fbox">
            <label for="correo"> <spring:message
                    code="registro.form.correo.label"
                    text="registro.form.correo.label" />
            </label>
            <form:input path="correo" />
            <form:errors path="correo" cssClass="ym-required" element="span" />
        </div>
        <div class="ym-fbox">
            <label for="nickname"> <spring:message
                    code="registro.form.nickname.label"
                    text="registro.form.nickname.label" />
            </label>
            <form:input path="nickname" />
            <form:errors path="nickname" cssClass="ym-required" element="span" />
        </div>
        <div class="ym-fbox">
            <label for="contrasena"> <spring:message
                    code="registro.form.contrasena.label"
                    text="registro.form.contrasena.label" />
            </label>
            <form:password path="contrasena" />
            <form:errors path="contrasena" cssClass="ym-required" element="span" />
        </div>
```

Please, help me solve this problem!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess `<mvc:interceptors>` does not apply the interceptor to the flows. Try adding the interceptor to your `<FlowHandlerMapping>`. Something like this (not knowing whether you can simply reference the interceptor you defined in `app-servlet.xml`):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="-1" />
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
                  p:paramName="lang"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```